# Is $[0,x)$ open on the topology of non-negative real numbers?

Tags: general-topology

Let our topological space be the set of non-negative real numbers (including 0).  I just want to verify something.  If we define the interval that goes from 0 inclusively to some positive real number $x$ (excluded), i.e., $[0,x)$, is that set open?  My understanding is that yes.  If the topology was the real line, it would definitely not be due to including 0, but in the topological space of non-negative numbers, including 0 is not a problem since any point in our topological space within a distance $d$ must be above 0.  Is that correct?

Comment: Your understanding is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply !